# matplotlib: change active axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple objects that visualize different things. They all are passed a reference to a single Figure instance and create their own axes objects (only one of them is active at the same time)

Code for demonstration would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# the visualization objects are jupyter widgets in production code
%matplotlib widget
plt.ioff()

def update_fig(f):
    f.canvas.draw()
    f.canvas.flush_events()

f = plt.figure()

# first visualizer is created and plots into the figure
ax1 = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="visualizer_1")
img1 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (20, 20, 3))
vis1 = ax1.imshow(img1)
update_fig(f)

# second visualizer is created and plots into the figure
ax2 = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="visualizer_2")
vis2 = ax2.plot(np.linspace(0, 5), 2 * np.linspace(0, 5))
update_fig(f)
```

How can I then switch which axes to show in the plot?
Already tried `plt.sca(ax1)` to go back to the first visualization but that did not work.

Of course I could use a different figure for each visualization object but since I have many of them, I would rather avoid that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You are creating two `Axes` on top of each other. Do you want to show them both at the same time (in which case, use `add_subplot(1,2,[1,2])`? Or do you want to clear you axes and plot a new plot the second time around (in which case use `plt.cla()`). Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Only one kind of visualizer is active at the same time plotting his data into the figure, e.g.  one that always does `ax.imshow` (with possibly different data).  The user might then select a different visualizer (e.g. one that always uses the `ax.plot` command) and only the content of its axes should then be shown in the figure. I thought it might then be possible to switch back to the first visualizer and getting back the `imshow` kind of plot (which can then be updated with new data). Effectively i want to be able to switch between different plot modes in the same figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Axes.set_visible([True|False])`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) to show or hide a specific axis at any time.

```
f = plt.figure()

# first visualizer is created and plots into the figure
ax1 = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="visualizer_1")
img1 = np.random.randint(0, 256, (20, 20, 3))
vis1 = ax1.imshow(img1)
update_fig(f)

# second visualizer is created and plots into the figure
ax1.set_visible(False)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="visualizer_2")
vis2 = ax2.plot(np.linspace(0, 5), 2 * np.linspace(0, 5))
update_fig(f)

ax2.set_visible(False) # hide ax2
ax1.set_visible(True) # show ax1 again.
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work exactly as I wanted it to work!